# Jquery boxy creates boxy with the same id at each time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, boxy

i Am Using Jquery Boxy In My Rails Application.

I have used

```
function rateboxy(id){
    var box = new Boxy(jQuery('#rate_'+id),{
    title: "Rate",
    draggable: false,
    closeable: true,
    center: true,
    modal: true
    });
    return false;
  }
```

I have a div

```
<div id="rate_<%= blog.id%>" style="display:none">
....
<div>
```

Each time when i click on the link

```
<%= link_to "Rate","#",:onclick=>"rateboxy('#{blog.id}');" %>
```

It opens a boxy modal. I have some update function inside the boxy which will update the html inside the div with its response.

But when i click on the link many times. Each time it creates a new boxy with the same id , so its not updating the old opened boxy, which i found out in firebug. 
How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are creating a new Boxy element every time your link is clicked within your rateboxy() function.

Move your div declaration outside of the function:

```
var box = new Boxy(jQuery('#rate_'+id),{
    title: "Rate",
    draggable: false,
    closeable: true,
    center: true,
    modal: true
    });
```

And then have your link just toggle the visibility of the existing div. Not sure for rails but in jQuery this would be:

```
function rateboxy(id){    
 jQuery("#"+id).toggle();
}
```